# How to avoid anti-aliasing in StableDiffusion output images?

Tags: stable-diffusion, lora

I'm running `stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0` with the `madebyollin/sdxl-vae-fp16-fix` vae and custom lora weights.

The lora was trained on a dataset of thousands of 512x512 images that contained no anti-aliased images. i.e pixel perfect edges.

The lora training python script was run with a 512 resolution parameter, and I set `interpolation=transforms.InterpolationMode.NEAREST, antialias=False` just in case it wanted to resize anything.

The output from Stable Diffusion with the lora applied has anti-aliased output, see below.

Current Output vs. Ideal Output:

[image: current output vs desired output]

Does anyone have tips on how I may be able to get Stable Diffusion to output images without any anti-aliasing? Is it the lora? The vae? The initial 512 lora training size? Or just not at all possible with SD?